# How do I eliminate this TypeError?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I select an item from the menu on the Spreadsheet, I get the following error. I cannot figure out how to fix this. Can someone suggest, please? I am not a coder; just trying to hack this together. Please be specific (and gentle)! :)

Thanks!

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setColumnFilterCriteria')**

My Apps Script is:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('NWEF Filters')
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Filter by Person')
          .addItem('Filter by Andrew', 'filter_Vogel')
          .addItem('Filter by Linford', 'filter_Linford'))
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Filter by Department')
          .addItem('Filter by Food Trucks', 'filter_foodTruck'))
      .addToUi();
}

// DEPARTMENTS GO HERE (ALPHABETICALLY) -- corresponds to Column C in the spreadsheet
function filter_foodTruck() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master List of Items").activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:Z').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenTextContains('Food Trucks')
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(3, criteria);
};

// PEOPLE GO HERE (ALPHABETICALLY) -- corresponds to Column D in the spreadsheet
function filter_Vogel() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master List of Items").activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:Z').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenTextContains('Vogel')
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(3, criteria);
};

function filter_Linford() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master List of Items").activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:Z').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenTextContains('Linford')
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(3, criteria);
};
```

Executing the script expecting it to filter the views. Instead, received this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setColumnFilterCriteria')**

Comment: Can you try to change the code as is shown in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setcolumnfiltercriteriacolumnposition,-filtercriteria)? - maybe the `spreadsheet` variable is null.

Comment: Is there a filter on the sheet? If not it getFilter() returns nulll

Comment: I may be missing something here but... taking `filter_foodTruck` 1) `spreadsheet.getRange('A:Z').createFilter();` = **creates a filter** 2) `spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();` = **deletes the filter** 3) `spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(3, criteria);` = tries to "get" a **non-existent filter**.